# printf() does not support the %f format

Tags: computer-science

The printf() function on your platform does not support the %f formatter.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling.  I don't, however, think this is a puzzle...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a programming interview question.

Comment: So, either use another platform or another format. Or perhaps another printf.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

> multiply the argument by 100

then

> print it as an integer (%d)

and finally

> insert a decimal separator before the second to last digit.

Comment: I think you may have just done some kid's homework assignment for them.